# Signing an OAuth request with an array parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, oauth, signing

I'm having a problem when signing an OAuth request that contains an array in the URL parameters.
Here's an example of a URL i want to sign:

> http://example.com/oauth1/products?filter[categorie]=myCategorie&page=1

I'm using [OAuthSignatureJS](https://github.com/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js) to generate the signature, and it works perfectly when passing simple parameters but when adding an array is returns an **Invalid Signature** response.
I tried using a JSON instead of url but still the same, and i can't change the API server code.

This is the calling function(AngularJS)

```
var request = generateRequest('GET', 'products', page, 'myCategorie');
request = request+'&page='+page+'&filter[categorie]=myCategorie';
$http.get(request, {timeout: config.timeout})
.success(function(json, status, headers, config){
})
.error(function(error){
    console.log(error);
})
```

And this is the function i use to generate the request

```
var generateRequest = function(method, route, page = null, categorie = null) {
    var timestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    var nonce = generateNonce();
    var parameters = {
        oauth_consumer_key: api.key,
        oauth_nonce: nonce,
        oauth_timestamp: timestamp,
        oauth_signature_method: api.signature,
        oauth_version: api.version
    };

    if(page) parameters.page = page;

    if(categorie) {
        parameters.filter = [];
        parameters.filter['categorie'] = categorie;
        console.log(parameters);
    }

    var link = 'http://example.com/oauth1/' + route;

    // Generating the signature with OauthSignatureJS
    var signature = oauthSignature.generate(method, link, parameters, api.secret);
    var authentification = '?oauth_consumer_key='+api.key+'&oauth_signature_method='+api.signature+'&oauth_version='+api.version+'&oauth_timestamp='+timestamp+'&oauth_nonce='+nonce+'&oauth_signature='+signature;

    return link+authentification;
}
```

When passing the filter[categorie] parameter in the URL, the server respond with a 401 Unauthorized message.

```
Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match
```

Is there something wrong with my code or is it the OauthSignature JS library ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, i just needed to add the filter array as a string to the parameters object `parameters['filter[categorie]'] = categorie;`

So this is the new working code

```
var generateRequest = function(method, route, page = null, categorie = null) {
    var timestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    var nonce = generateNonce();
    var parameters = {
        oauth_consumer_key: api.key,
        oauth_nonce: nonce,
        oauth_timestamp: timestamp,
        oauth_signature_method: api.signature,
        oauth_version: api.version
    };

    if(page) parameters.page = page;

    if(categorie) parameters['filter[categorie]'] = categorie; 

    var link = 'http://example.com/oauth1/' + route;

    // Generating the signature with OauthSignatureJS
    var signature = oauthSignature.generate(method, link, parameters, api.secret);
    var authentification = '?oauth_consumer_key='+api.key+'&oauth_signature_method='+api.signature+'&oauth_version='+api.version+'&oauth_timestamp='+timestamp+'&oauth_nonce='+nonce+'&oauth_signature='+signature;

    return link+authentification;
}
```